# R: Split weighted column into equal-sized buckets

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to use something like dplyr's `cut_number` to split a column into buckets with approximately the same number of observations, where my dataset is in a compact form where each row has a weight (number of observations).

Example data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
    x=c(18,17,18.5,20,20.5,24,24.4,18.3,31,34,39,20,19,34,23),
    weight=c(1,10,3,6,19,20,34,66,2,3,1,6,9,15,21)
)
```

If there were one observation of x per row, I would simply use `df$bucket <- cut_number(df$x,3)` to segment `x` into 3 buckets with approximately the same number of observations. But how do I take into account the fact that each row is weighted with some number of observations? I'd like to avoid splitting each row into `weight` rows since the original dataframe already has millions of rows.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you want these buckets made? Should bucket one contain x1-xn, bucket 2 xn+1-xm, etc? Or should each bucket contain as close to sum(weight)/number_of_buckets x's?

Comment: The latter: each bucket should contain as close to sum(weight)/number_of_buckets x's as possible.

Comment: This seems like a simple problem of creating intervals, but I'm unclear on the desired output. If your data are `df <- data.frame(x=1:6, weight=c(1,1,1,1,4,1))`, do you draw the buckets as `123|455|556` or `123|45|6` (where `|` denotes a bucket boundary)?

Comment: In my application, every row should be assigned a unique bucket. So out of your two suggested partitions, the former would be inadmissible and I'd pick the latter.

Comment: Does my answer work for you in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, I think this may be the interval set you are seeking. Apologies for the general un-R-ness of it:

```
dfTest <- data.frame(x=1:6, weight=c(1,1,1,1,4,1))

f <- function(df, n) {
  interval <- round(sum(df$weight) / n)
  buckets <- vector(mode="integer", length(nrow(df)))
  bucketNum <- 1
  count <- 0
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    count <- count + df$weight[i]
    buckets[i] <- bucketNum
    if (count >= interval) {
      bucketNum <- bucketNum + 1
      count <- 0
    }
  }
  return(buckets)
}
```

Running this function buckets items as follows:

```
dfTest$bucket <- f(dfTest, 3)

#    x weight bucket
#  1 1      1      1
#  2 2      1      1
#  3 3      1      1
#  4 4      1      2
#  5 5      4      2
#  6 6      1      3
```

For your example:

```
df$bucket <- f(df, 3)
#        x weight bucket
#  1  18.0      1      1
#  2  17.0     10      1
#  3  18.5      3      1
#  4  20.0      6      1
#  5  20.5     19      1
#  6  24.0     20      1
#  7  24.4     34      1
#  8  18.3     66      2
#  9  31.0      2      2
#  10 34.0      3      2
#  11 39.0      1      2
#  12 20.0      6      3
#  13 19.0      9      3
#  14 34.0     15      3
#  15 23.0     21      3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach, based on my assumption that you have in total x1*weight1 + x2*weight2 +..... observations. Furthermore, each 'unique' observation can only be in one bucket. The approach uses sorting and the cumulative sum of the weights to create the buckets.

```
#sort data
df <- df[order(df$x),]

#calculate cumulative weights (this is why we sort)
df$cumulative_weight <- cumsum(df$weight)

#create bucket by cumulative weight
n_buckets <- 3
df$bucket <- cut(df$cumulative_weight, n_buckets)

#check: calculate total number of observations per bucket   


> aggregate(weight~bucket,FUN=sum, data=df)
       bucket weight
1 (9.79,78.7]     77
2  (78.7,147]     64
3   (147,216]     75
```